# lemmatization inside array using nltk python

Tags: python, arrays, nltk, lemmatization

i'm new using python and i dont know how to lemmatize an array.
what i do is

```
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
lmtzr = WordNetLemmatizer()
data = 'data/new 1.txt'
file_tagged = open(data)
verses_tagged = file_tagged.readlines()
num_lines = sum(1 for line in open(data))
i = 0
dataPair = []
tokenP1 = []
tokenP2 = []

def tokenPhrasebase(verse):
    return verse.split('}')

for i in range(0, num_lines):
    dataPair.append(verses_tagged[i].split('\t'))

    tokenP1.append(tokenPhrasebase(dataPair[i][0]))
    tokenP2.append(tokenPhrasebase(dataPair[i][1]))

    for j in range(len(tokenP1[i])):
        tokenP1[i][j] = tagRemoval(tokenP1[i][j])
    for j in range(len(tokenP2[i])):
        tokenP2[i][j] = tagRemoval(tokenP2[i][j])

    for y in range(0, num_lines):
        tokenP1[y] = lmtzr.lemmatize(tokenP1[y])
        tokenP2[y] = lmtzr.lemmatize(tokenP2[y])
```

what i want to do is lemmatize all string inside array without changing the array formation. but i get an error like this `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`
anyone can help?

Comment: Why can't you lemmatize and remove the tags at the same time?

Comment: @cricket_007 when i try it, it appear an error like this : 
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: Lemmatising the individual strings (tokens) inside the list is what you need to do. If you have a decoding error, then you should probably open the input file with the correct encoding. (1) find out the right encoding (eg. 'utf8', 'latin1', 'cp1252'. (2) open with `open(data, encoding=<ENC>)`, replacing <ENC> with the result from step (1).

Comment: In case you're using Python 2, then `import codecs` and open the file with `codecs.open(data, 'r', encoding=<ENC>)`. But you really should be using Python 3 if you start with Python now.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are trying to use an array of arrays instead of an array of tokens in your lemmatizer. **You can see a working example below:**

```
import pandas as pd
import nltk as nl
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
from nltk.tokenize import RegexpTokenizer

# reading the data in lower case
    dbFilepandas = pd.read_csv('yourfilename.csv').apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.lower())

# declaring the lemmatizer to use
lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()

# Getting the data as an array of strings
train = []
# I am only using the first 4 columns of the file
for sentences in dbFilepandas[dbFilepandas.columns[0:4]].values:
    str1 = ''.join(sentences)
    train.append(str1)
# removing punctuation
tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer(r'\w+')
# get the tokens
tokens_to_lematize = [tokenizer.tokenize(sentences) for sentences in train]

filtered_tokens_Array = []
for item in tokens_to_lematize:
    words = [lemmatizer.lemmatize(word) for word in item]
    #removing stopwords
    filtered_words = [word for word in words if word not in nl.corpus.stopwords.words('english')]
    filtered_tokens_Array.append(filtered_words)
```

Now, if you print the filtered_tokens_Array you have the tokens "lemmatized"

```
 print("\nfiltered:\n",filtered_tokens_Array)
```

**[example output]:**

filtered:
 [['men', 'shirt', 'running', 'color', 'yellow', 'size', 'springfield'], ['men', 'shirt', 'passed', 'color', 'red', 'size', 'springfield'], ['woman', 'shirt', 'color', 'green',
'size', 'springfield'], ['men', 'shirt', 'color', 'red', 'size', 'l', 'springfield']]